# ¿Cómo puedo determinar un valor de una consulta basado en los valores de una tabla hijo?

Tags: sql-server

Tengo una tabla llamada pedido

```
noorden, fecha, idusuario
```

y una tabla pedido_detalle

```
noorden, idproducto, idservicio
```

un ejemplo de datos puede ser el siguiente:

```
tabla pedido: [
    {noorden = 720, fecha = '2018-10-10', idusuario = 1}, 
    {noorden = 721, fecha = '2018-10-11', idusuario = 1},
    {noorden = 722, fecha = '2018-10-11', idusuario = 1}
]
tabla pedido_detalle: [
    {noorden = 720, idproducto = 1, idservicio = 1}, 
    {noorden = 720, idproducto = 2, idservicio = 1}, 
    {noorden = 720, idproducto = 1,idservicio = 2}, 
    {noorden = 721, idproducto = 1, idservicio = 1},
    {noorden = 722, idproducto = 1, idservicio = 2}
]
```

Deseo obtener el resultado de la siguiente manera:

```
tabla pedido: [
    {noorden = 720, fecha = '2018-10-10', idusuario = 1, servicio = 'ambos'}, 
    {noorden = 721, fecha = '2018-10-11', idusuario = 1, servicio = 'servicio1'},
    {noorden = 721, fecha = '2018-10-11', idusuario = 1, servicio = 'servicio2'}
]
```

Mi consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT TOP 3
    [P].[noorden],
    [P].[fecha],
    [P].[idusuario],
    (
        CASE
            WHEN [PD].[idservicio] = 1 THEN 'servicio1'
            WHEN [PD].[idservicio] = 2 THEN 'servicio2'
            //¿aqui me falta algo para determinar el valor ambos?
        END
    ) [servicio]
FROM [pedido] [P]
JOIN [pedido_petalle] [PD] ON [PD].[noorden] = [P].[noorden]
WHERE [P].[idusuario] = 1
```

Pero al intentar este query, el pedido con número de orden 720 aparece duplicado. ¿Cómo puedo obtener el resultado deseado?

Comment: ¿Sólo quieres reportar los servicios 1 y 2?

Comment: Necesito conocer si el servicio es 1, 2 o ambos por cada uno de los pedidos, basándose en el tipo de servicio que se tengan en pedido_detalle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que lo que podrías hacer es lo siguiente:

```
SELECT  P.noorden,
    P.fecha,
    P.idusuario,
    CASE    WHEN PD1.idservicio IS NOT NULL AND PD2.idservicio IS NOT NULL THEN 'ambos'
            WHEN PD1.idservicio IS NOT NULL THEN 'servicio1'
            WHEN PD2.idservicio IS NOT NULL THEN 'servicio2'
            ELSE 'ninguno'
    END
    FROM pedido P
    LEFT JOIN pedido_petalle PD1
        ON PD1.noorden = P.noorden
        AND PD1.idservicio = 1
    LEFT JOIN pedido_petalle PD2
        ON PD2.noorden = P.noorden
        AND PD2.idservicio = 2
    WHERE P.idusuario = 1
```

- Hacemos dos `LEFT JOIN` para cada servicio/pedido
- Entonces el `CASE` es trivial, si tenemos filas en ambos `JOIN` tenemos ambos servicios, sino simplemente verificamos cual tenemos.

Nota: En caso de tener más de un mismo servicio como has mencionado en un comentario, deberías agregar un `DISTINCT` a la consulta o eventualmente un `GROUP BY`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  P.noorden,
        P.fecha,
        P.idusuario,
        MAX(CASE    WHEN PD1.idservicio IS NOT NULL AND PD2.idservicio IS NOT NULL THEN 'ambos'
                    WHEN PD1.idservicio IS NOT NULL THEN 'servicio1'
                    WHEN PD2.idservicio IS NOT NULL THEN 'servicio2'
                    ELSE 'ninguno'
            END)
    FROM pedido P
    LEFT JOIN pedido_petalle PD1
        ON PD1.noorden = P.noorden
        AND PD1.idservicio = 1
    LEFT JOIN pedido_petalle PD2
        ON PD2.noorden = P.noorden
        AND PD2.idservicio = 2
    WHERE P.idusuario = 1
    GROUP BY P.noorden,
             P.fecha,
             P.idusuario
```

Otra forma posible de resolverlo es mediante una subconsulta agrupada solo de los servicios 1 y 2 y obteniendo el mínimo y máximo

```
SELECT  P.noorden,
        P.fecha,
        P.idusuario,
        CASE    WHEN PD.idservicio1 = 1 AND PD.idservicio1 = 2 THEN 'ambos'
                WHEN PD.idservicio1 = 1                        THEN 'servicio1'
                WHEN PD.idservicio1 = 2                        THEN 'servicio2'
                ELSE 'ninguno'
        END
    FROM pedido P
    LEFT JOIN (select   d.noorden,
                        MIN(d.idservicio) idservicio1,
                        MAX(d.idservicio) idservicio2
                from pedido_petalle d
                inner join pedido c
                     on c.noorden = d.noorden
                     and c.idusuario = 1
                where d.idservicio in (1,2)
                GROUP BY d.noorden) PD
           on PD.noorden = P.noorden
    WHERE P.idusuario = 1
```

Comment: Hola, esto resuelve la consulta que el esta realizando, pero no es la manera mas optima de realizar la consulta.

Comment: @MartinAlejandroPastoraMendi, ¿Por qué dices que no es la forma más óptima?

Comment: Porque se está realizando la consulta a la misma tabla dos veces, pongamos que no solo lo va a realizar para un usuario si no para todos

Comment: Entiendo tu punto, pero es discutible, en primer lugar ¿hay una solución alternativa mejor? y por otro lado sin saber como están definidos los índices es arriesgado cualquier definición al respecto. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para realizar este tipo de consultas podemos utilizar la caracteristica de los subquery de SQL.

Vamos a realizar primero el subquery, asumire que las fechas de los pedidos pueden ser diferente, por tal razon solo incluyo noorden y idusuario:

```
SELECT 
    [P].[noorden],
    [P].[idusuario],
    SUM([PD].[idservicio]) idservicio
FROM [pedido] [P]
INNER JOIN [pedido_petalle] [PD] ON [PD].[noorden] = [P].[noorden]
WHERE [P].[idusuario] = 1
GROUP BY [P].[noorden],
    [P].[idusuario]
```

La suma identifica si existe mas de un registro, esto funciona si solo tienes 2 servicios(1 y 2).

Luego realizamos la consulta final, que es unificar el subquer, con la sentencia final:

```
SELECT
[subquery].[noorden],
[P].[fecha],
[subquery].[idusuario],
CASE
    WHEN [subquery].[idservicio] = 1 THEN 'servicio1'
    WHEN [subquery].[idservicio] = 2 THEN 'servicio2'
    WHEN [subquery].[idservicio] = 3 THEN 'ambos'
END
FROM
(SELECT 
    [P].[noorden],
    [P].[idusuario],
    SUM([PD].[idservicio]) idservicio
FROM [pedido] [P]
INNER JOIN [pedido_petalle] [PD] ON [PD].[noorden] = [P].[noorden]
WHERE [P].[idusuario] = 1
GROUP BY [P].[noorden],
    [P].[idusuario]
) subquery
INNER JOIN [pedido] [P] ON subquery.noorden = [P].[noorden]
```

El join con la tabla [pedido]es para obtener la fecha real de la orden.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si tengo 2 `pedido_detalle` con `idservicio = 2` ?

Comment: Hola, por eso hice la aclaración eso resuelve si tus pedidos siempre serán 1 y 2. No que la orden 730 va a estar con el mismo servicio 2 veces. Si vas a tener ese escenario se tiene que redefinir la consulta. Pero tu duda creo que se resuelve con lo que puse.